# synonym not working ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid?

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

We have created a synonym in DB but when we trying to execute the synonym then it gives error `ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid.` we have another clone environment, there the same synonym is working fine. Can any one please help me on that.

Comment: Can anyone has solution for clone DB issue. please help I am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Various reasons are possible. For example:

- synonym is based on a table/view/other synonym which has been dropped, and that invalidated the synonym you're selecting from
- if some of these objects (you used to create the synonym) belong to other user(s), they might have revoked privileges you previously had
- you created a synonym based on object that doesn't exist; for example, you misspelled table's name (e.g. DPET instead of DEPT)

What to do? Check options I mentioned and recreate the synonym.

Comment: thanks for response. I have checked these. On another clone environment synonym is working fine. this clone DB is just created and I am getting this issue. the difference between both clone is SID. rest username,hostname and port are same. I am able to understand what the problem is?

Comment: For which object did you create the synonym?

Comment: I have a schema A. In schema A there is a table having name TABLE_ABC. I have to create a synonym of table TABLE_ABC in schema B. for that I create synonym by executing ```CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM TABLE_ABC FOR A.TABLE_ABC;```. Now we created one more DB clone. I have created the synonym but getting the error in new environment.

Comment: Did user A run `grant select on table_abc to b;`?